# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel [Windows Server 2012 R2]

Tags: c#, windows-server-2012-r2

I use code below to download HTML from the web address:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

var html = @"https://example.com/page";
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var htmlDoc = web.Load(html);
```

The above code is working perfectly in my computer [Windows 10 Pro] and not working in the production [Windows Server 2012 R2 x64].

Any idea why it is not working?

Comment: What's the TLS version of your prod server?

Comment: Have you followed the instructions here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392 to enable TLS 1.2 on the server

Comment: @gkb How can I know the TLS version in the prod server?

Comment: @good-to-know take a look https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn786418(v=ws.11)